# Is it useful to use requestanimationframe when javascript updates a class?

Tags: javascript, css, requestanimationframe

**Context**

I learnt that when I want to keep fluidity on my UI, instead of:

```
document.querySelector('#div').style.width = '100px';
```

I can use:

```
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
  document.querySelector('#div').style.width = '100px';
});
```

**Question**

Is it useful to do the same thing for a class change? I mean is this:

```
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    document.querySelector('#div').classList.add('big');
});
```

useful to keep a good UI fluidity?

**Note**

I have also learned, with the video of Jake about the Javascript event loop, that CSS is applied on a different *thread* than Javascript, hence my question because since it is Javascript sending the class change, does it is counted as part of the JS event loop or the CSS event loop?

Comment: Where did you learnt that? Sounds like some info has been missed somewhere. FWIW, doing it in a rAF callback or not will be about the same, what really matters is that you don't cause a reflow with your script after you change the CSSOM, so that this reflow is done only once per frame at most. Now, where rAF can be useful, is when you do this change in reaction to an event that can fire several times per frame. rAF can then be used as a mean to control a debounce function, making sure that a single callback will get called per frame.

Comment: For the record, I simplified my issue, I am actually on an SVG engine that apply transformations over thousands of elements in a raw, and without rAF I can *clearly* see the difference (I go from 15 FPS on my smartphone to nearly 60). What I learned can be found on this video: [Jake Archibald: In The Loop - JSConf.Asia 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0).

Comment: so you are in an animation? Please explain better your use case. Once again, rAF will just delay the operation until just before the next screen refresh. There is no reason it would perform any better than at a deterministic moment (dunno from where the main call is made..). But yes, if you are doing an animation then by all means use rAF as the way to drive it. No other method is able to ensure only one call per screen refresh.

Comment: Yes indead I created my own SVG map engine, so it supports drag & drop of the SVG, zoom in and zoom out. There is also a search feature that apply a transformation on the scale, so you can see your element "pop out" when you search for a particular element (by name, using data-* attribute). I apply the pop out transformation on, sometimes, hundreds of element, I just compared with and without rAF there is clearly a difference. Now my question was not necessarily about is it useful to use rAF in general, but more like is it useful with a CSS class change to use it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you shouldn't do this unless you know why you want it.

Your "fluidity" introduced by RAF is actually caused by moving the change from "do it now" to "do it when you're drawing next".

[image: Chart of redraws, credit dev.opera.com]

[Image credit, as well as a good resource for learning more.](https://dev.opera.com/articles/better-performance-with-requestanimationframe/)

Comment: I edited my question to clarify my question. So do you confirm asking the browser to wait for applying a class is not necessary?

Comment: It depends on how often you're doing it and if it happens during repaints or not.